# How expensive is parking in Dachstein?

Tags: automobiles, hiking, austria, alps

I'm planning to hike in Dachstein this September and I consider getting there by car. Only information that I can't find is the cost of parking somewhere near trail entrance. I'm not looking for exact price of particular parking, but rather estimation for the whole region.

So, can you tell me how much approximately will I have to pay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a good chance of parking for free - parking spaces near hiking trails are generally small and trying to enforce a charge would not be cost-efficient. If there happens to be a larger parking lot with a charge, it will probably be at most 5 EUR for the whole day.